# Why does easywsdl prepend each class with 3 random characters?

Tags: java, android-ksoap2, easywsdl

I have been using the `easywsdl` Android Studio plugin to autogenerate `ksoap2` code based on a `wsdl`.

Each time I generate the code, `easywsdl` prepends 3 random upper-case characters to the java class names.

Question is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 3 random characters are added in Free account only. For premium, you can define a prefix for classes (or you can generate without any prefix).

Comment: so its an annoyance to encourage you to pay for the premium version - hey it works, i paid for the premium version..

Comment: Basically free account is to check if the generator works with your web service. So you pay only when you know that this tool works good.